# How can I develop a 0-100 composite or index score using multiple Z scores from multiple independent variables?

Tags: python, mean, z-score, pandas

I'm really interested in index scores like the [human development index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Development_Index) or [economic freedom index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_Economic_Freedom) where they rank things on a 0-100 scale based off of a bunch of different variables (e.g. press freedom, property rights, etc). I would like to do this with z-scores for multiple columns in a Python notebook.

I'm able to calculate the Z scores just fine using scipy:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
no_income_data_important_columns_only.apply(zscore)
```

and get something like:[image] I understand these z-scores are telling me how high or low the values are relative to the average. But now I want to be able to understand how high or low each row is **across** all of the measurements/columns...

I don't really know what to do with all the Z-scores in order to calculate an index or composite score (on a 0 to 100 scale). Do I multiply them or add them together or do something else to aggregate them?

Comment: How you combine the z-scores depends on the importance of each. If equally important, the just an ordinary average. Otherwise, an appropriately weighted average. I can't immediately imagine a scenario in which multiplication would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a composite z-score that is roughly normal with mean approximately 0 and standard deviation approximately 1. Then transforming with the standard normal CDF $\Phi$ (`pnorm` in R) will give you scores that are approximately uniformly distributed on $(0,1).$ Multiplying by 100 will give you 'index' scores between $0$ and $100.$

Here is an example in R, beginning with z-scores for 250 simulated items.

```
set.seed(2020)
z = rnorm(250)  # population mean 0 and SD 1 are the default
summary(z);  length(z);  sd(z)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-3.056684 -0.739665  0.067159  0.006864  0.710861  3.201632 
[1] 250
[1] 1.120193
u = pnorm(z)    # approx uniformly distributed on (0,1)
summary(u)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.001119 0.229755 0.526771 0.504363 0.761384 0.999317 
x = 100*u       # proposed index scores
summary(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.1119 22.9755 52.6771 50.4363 76.1384 99.9317 
[1] 30.30388

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Z Scores"); rug(z)
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Index Scores"); rug(x)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Maybe it is a good idea to start your answer right with your comment you've given to the point how the "composite" (averaged) z-score could be obtained first.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I know Python but don't know R so I'm just trying to follow this. 

Not quite sure how I'd apply this. But the histogram of the z scores vs. the index scores definitely makes sense.

Where does `u` come from? Or rather, how would I work with u across, say, 6 columns?

Comment: If $U\sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ and $X$ has CDF $F_X,$ then $F_X^{-1}(U)$ is a random variable with CDF $F_X.$ $F_X^{-1},$ is called the _quantile_ function of $X,$ so this is called the quantile function method of simulating realizations of $X.$ Accordingly, if $X$ has CDF $F_X,$ then $F_X(X)\sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$ The usual symbol for the CDF of a std normal RV is $\Phi$ (`pnorm` in R; what is it in Python?). Thus, if $Z\sim\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ then $\Phi(Z)\sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$ // In English: transforming a std normal by $\Phi$ gives a random variable $U=\Phi(Z)\sim\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$

Comment: Computer packages such as R and Python can be enormously helpful in probability computations and statistical analysis, but it is a mistake to tie your fundamental understanding of concept of probability or statistics so directly to particular software that you can't discuss it outside that context. // Perhaps that's why this site generally discourages questions narrowly focused on debugging computer programs or implementing a kind of analysis specifically in _one particular_ 'brand' of software: whether Excel, SPSS, Minitab, Stata, R, Python, MatLab, SAS, or other.